Wrong Phone number displaying
Several of us here notice that the wrong phone number showing in our website footer vs. what is in the HTML. Our toll free number is 877-448-0000 but a different number appears - and that number is different for different people.
The content block in Magento is correct. The number in the View Page Source HTML is also correct, yet it displays in Chrome as a different number.
Any idea what is causing this?

Maybe is cache from page, try include in ur url nocache=1231231
Example:
https://magento2.docker/policy-program?nocache=213123
Try too, clear cache from ur browser.
